# Trouble adding a Workflow Activity to the Toolbox from a PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, workflow-foundation-4, nuget

I’m creating a PowerShell Script (for NuGet) that can add System.Activities Workflow Activities to the Toolbox.

Currently I’m installing them with C# code written as a cmdlet but this causes problems when you try to uninstall the package since NuGet has the assembly loaded and it can’t be deleted.

My goal is to do everything from PowerShell so I don’t have to load the assembly.  I’m very close except the last line where I add the toolbox item blows up with "Object must implement IConvertible." Which leads me to believe it thinks that something I’m passing to it is the wrong type..  I do know that the $toolbox interface is working because it does add a tab to the toolbox.

```
function AddActivity ( 
[string] $activity, 
[string] $assemblyFullname,  
[string] $name,  
[string] $category, 
[string] $bitmapPath)
{
    Write-Host "Argument List"
    Write-Host $activity
    Write-Host $assemblyFullname 
    Write-Host $name  
    Write-Host $category 
    Write-Host $bitmapPath

    Write-Host "Loading assemblies"
    $assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop")

    Write-Host "get the toolbox service"
    Write-Host "get the toolbox service"
    $ServiceType = [System.Type]::GetType("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsToolbox,{0}" -f $assembly.FullName)      
    $InterfaceType = [System.Type]::GetType("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolbox,{0}" -f $assembly.FullName) 
    $toolbox = Get-VSService $ServiceType $InterfaceType    

    Write-Host "Add a Tab"
    $tlBoxTab = $toolbox.AddTab($category)

    Write-Host "Create the DataObject"
    $dataObject = New-Object Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleDataObject
    $dataObject.SetData("AssemblyName", $assemblyFullname)
    $dataObject.SetData("CF_WORKFLOW_4", $name) 
    $dataObject.SetData("WorkflowItemTypeNameFormat", ('{0}{1}' -f $activity, $assemblyFullname))

    Write-Host "Load the bitmap {0}" $bitmapPath
    Write-Host "$bitmapPath"
    $bitmap = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap $bitmapPath

    $toolboxItemInfo = new-object Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.TBXITEMINFO;
    $toolboxItemInfo.bstrText = $name
    $toolboxItemInfo.hBmp = $bitmap.GetHbitmap()
    $toolboxItemInfo.clrTransparent = [System.UInt32][System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::ToWin32([System.Drawing.Color]::White)

    #Create an array with one element
    $tbiArray = [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.TBXITEMINFO[]] ($toolboxItemInfo)

    Write-Host "Add the item - this will blow up"
    $toolbox.AddItem($dataObject, $tbiArray, $category) 

    # Exception calling "AddItem" with "3" argument(s): "Exception calling "InvokeMethod" with "3" argument(s): "Object must implement IConvertible.""
    # At C:\users\rojacobs\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WorkflowConsoleApplication24\packages\Microsoft.Activities.1.8.4.630\tools\install.ps1:53 char:21
    # +     $toolbox.AddItem <<<< ($dataObject, $tbiArray, $category)    
    #     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    #     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodRuntimeException
}
```

Comment: Hey! Mr Ron Server AppFabric Jacobs! I'll take a look at this for you (being both a NuGet core developer responsible for much powershell stuff, and also an MS powershell MVP makes me well qualified I think - and also I friggin' love your win server appfabric work :))

Comment: btw, a lot of these problems occur in powershell because of the way COM objects are wrapped with an "adapter" which works with the typelib to expose a user friendly experience optimized for interactive and scripting use. Often you think you're passing a PIA or a raw COM reference, but you're not. This leads to all sorts of problems when you're trying to call managed APIs that expect a PIA or otherwise.

Comment: Yes - I've got most of the internal folks stumped with this one.  What I've learned so far is that the exception is actually being thrown because NuGetConsole.Host.MethodBinder.ChangeType thinks it needs to change the type of something.  I've asked the NuGet guys for help so we will see what comes up.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Nope - gave up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Ron, I believe the issue may be surrounding the category.  According to the documentation I looked at the category needs to be the localized name (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivstoolbox.additem.aspx) which you can recover using GetIDOfTab (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivstoolbox3.getidoftab.aspx).

Let me know if this helps.